# How to make numberOfRowsInSection be the length of an array within an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

The way I currently have my `UITableView` set up, `_matchCenterArray` is defined like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Delay to allow MatchCenter item enough time to be added before pinging ebay
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{}
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}
```

`result` is an array of arrays, and it typically looks like this:

```
Result: '(
        {
        "Top 3" =         (
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mu05CM1bactFTAWZjesohNg/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nexus-7-Latest-Model-16GB-Wi-Fi-7in-Black-2nd-Generation-2013-/281443895415?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "170.0";
                Title = "Nexus 7 (Latest Model) 16GB, Wi-Fi, 7in - Black (2nd) Generation 2013";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mjkaCfDBdTQ6S-VTD0kFimA/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Asus-Google-Nexus-7-2nd-Generation-Tablet-7-16GB-Android-4-3-/351173222631?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "165.59";
                Title = "Asus Google Nexus 7 2nd Generation Tablet 7\" 16GB Android 4.3 ";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mjIENDWxrHTfcrO_Tmu4-zw/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Google-Nexus-7-16GB-HD-K008-NEXUS7-ASUS-2B16-2nd-Gen-Tablet-Priority-Ship-/301315740555?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "164.99";
                Title = "Google Nexus 7 16GB HD K008 NEXUS7 ASUS-2B16 2nd Gen Tablet Priority Ship";
            },
                        {
                "Search Term" = "nexus 7 16gb";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        "Top 3" =         (
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mbSjXw608gtlLhYC5GbrbOg/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/rolex-datejust-/301318985642?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "400.0";
                Title = "rolex datejust";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mx2eBCLXBEY30DXIIMrm_MQ/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/VINTAGE-LADIES-ROLEX-STANDARD-17J-GOLD-FILLED-WATCH-WORKING-NICE-/111466728842?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "349.99";
                Title = "VINTAGE LADIES ROLEX STANDARD 17J GOLD FILLED WATCH WORKING NICE  ";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mj7-GblU-4Al2X5q0sRvkfw/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rolex-17000-Quartz-Datejust-BLACK-DIAL-5035-/271610085029?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "400.0";
                Title = "Rolex 17000 Quartz Datejust  BLACK DIAL 5035";
            },
                        {
                "Search Term" = rolex;
            }
        );
    }
)'
```

For the number of sections in my table, I have it set up to take the number of "Top 3" arrays, like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}
```

I want to do the same thing for the number of rows in each section, but I'm not sure how to lay out the syntax for that. I want it to be the length of each "Top 3" array. I currently have it set to just `return 3` as a makeshift, but due to eBay results, the "Top 3" isn't guaranteed to actually have 3, so I don't want to make it a hard number like that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try. 
Assuming: your matchCenterArray would be of this structure:

```
_matchCenterArray = @[ @[contentOfFirstTop3], @[contentOfSecondTop3] ]
```

The number of sections can be retrieved:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}
```

The number of rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *currentSectionArray = _matchCenterArray[section];
    return currentSectionArray.count;
}
```

Comment: Doing this makes each section have only 1 row. _matchCenterArray is structured as you assumed, as you can see in the example JSON I posted in the question. Any reason why it would be doing this?

Comment: Well, if you look at your JSON, Result: is an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary has one key/value pair, which is "Top 3" as key and an array of dictionaries again as value, so each array in your _matchCenterArray should contain the value of "Top 3". This way you would have the structure I mentioned in my answer, which is the one that makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows in each section, return `self.matchCenterArray[indexPath.section].count`. This returns the length of the subarray at that section index.

Comment: It would just be `section`, not `indexPath.section`.

Comment: This won't quite work, because `self.matchCenterArray[indexPath.section]` returns type `id`, not type `NSArray *`.  You need to cast it to `NSArray *` if you want to use dot syntax.  Or you can say `[self.matchCenterArray[section] count]`.